# how to change sequelize inner join output format

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a problem in Sequelize. I have a query than gets data through an inner join and the response data comes in the following format;

```
`item.Item_name`
```

how do i change the output to

```
`Item_name`
```

when using raw sql we use `as` to provide an alias to the query outputs. my question is how do i do that within sequelize. or is there any other method to fix this. or can anyone let me know the method to read the above data format within react-native.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For that , You need to define attributes at the top level of include :

```
attributes : [['item.Item_name','Item_name']]
```

> And I think , you are using **`raw:true`** in your query , that is why you
>   are getting name like that , **remove that** and you will get proper
>   nested values.